# Graphics card low graphics mode errors

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.10

Two days ago I updated my system. One of the updates was the nvidia driver.

While updating it asked me if I wanted to update some config file as well. It told me the recommended thing to do was to update this config file. Usually I never do so, but I did agree to upgrade those config files.

Today I started my PC and was greeted with this message:

[image]

[image]

After that I got a message box with the following options:

> **What information would you like to review?**
>   ⠀
>   □ Review the xserver log file
>   □ Review the startup errors
>   □ Edit configuration file

I tried to run it in low graphics mode, but there was no result. Then I tried to reinstall nvidia 331 drivers, but I had the same problem, nothing changed.

So does anyone know what can be done here?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install 331 using the xorg-edgers ppa? I was using that and ran into this same issue. I exited to the console and purged that ppa. Then I moved to their stable [x-swat track](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates). Once I reinstalled 331 from there I've had no issues.

Comment: Yes I am using that ppa, Well I will try to do the thing you mentioned

Comment: Did not work I tried nvidia 319, 304 and finally opensource drivers it did not work sadly

Comment: Did you try running sudo nvidia-xconfig after reboot? Or deleting the /etc/X11/xorg.conf?

Comment: sadly it did not work